# Next-Auth closing browser logs out user

Tags: cookies, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth, next.js13

My Next Auth (4.22.1) and NextJS (13.4.2) app works perfectly in dev mode.

Now that I have deployed it to a linux server, Next-Auth does not remember users after the browser is closed. The session and local storage cookie disappears.

I am using a credential provider (My ASP.NET backend).
I have tested my backend with Postman and it is working fine.
The linux server has an Nginx proxy handling the forwarding of [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to localhost:3000.

Has anyone else had this problem? What can I do to troubleshoot it?

New info:

I see this error message when I re-open my browser window.

```
Cookie “__Host-next-auth.csrf-token” has been rejected for invalid 
prefix.

Cookie “__Secure-next-auth.callback-url” has been rejected for 
invalid prefix.

Cookie “__Host-next-auth.csrf-token” has been rejected for invalid 
prefix.
```

My tokens (I changed the name of the site to mysite.com as an example):

```
__Host-next-auth.csrf-token
Created:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 12:04:05 GMT"
Domain:"mysite.com"
Expires / Max-Age:"Session"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:true
Last Accessed:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 12:04:05 GMT"
Path:"/"
SameSite:"Lax"
Secure:true
Size:158

__Secure-next-auth.callback-url:"https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com"
Created:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 12:04:05 GMT"
Domain:"mysite.com"
Expires / Max-Age:"Session"
Last Accessed:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 12:04:05 GMT"
Path:"/"
SameSite:"Lax"
Secure:true
Size:59

_Secure-next-auth.session-token:"blah..."
Created:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 00:25:52 GMT"
Domain:"mysite.com"
Expires / Max-Age:"Sun, 30 Jul 2023 12:08:10 GMT"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:true
Last Accessed:"Fri, 30 Jun 2023 12:08:11 GMT"
Path:"/"
Secure:true
Size:3559
```

Comment: I actually think it is NextJS generating static pages. So the "Login" button is no longer dynamic but static giving the appearance of the user not being logged in.